# Making Saxon XSLT engine more permissive (types mismatch error)

Tags: xslt, types, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am converting a large number of XSLs from a native XSL 1.0 syntax to be Saxon-XSL3 compatible.

A common merge error I tend to get is due to types mismatch, for example:

> XPTY0004: The required item type of the first argument of
> fn:string-length() is xs:string;   the supplied value 1 does not
> match. The supplied value is of type xs:integer

When I used MSXML 6.0 engine, this type of merge error was never raised.

My question is - can I somehow configure Saxon engine to be more permissive and ignore error of this sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option of running in 1.0 backwards-compatibility mode by specifying `version="1.0"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element. But my recommendation is to move forwards and make the changes needed for the stricter type-checking of 2.0+; the permissive 1.0 rules lead to many hard-to-detect errors.

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks!